# How Subtract and divide 3 subqueries with different date?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to substract two subqueries with date filter then divide them to last date purchased

Here is first query to know target sales on July:

```
select floor(sum(uorpd_qty * 20/100 + (uorpd_qty))) '20%'
from user_order_product
left join user_order on user_order_product.uor_id = user_order.uor_id 
where uor_status = 'completed'
and uorpd_is_free = 0
and date_format(uor_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2019-07-01'
and date_format(uor_date, '%Y-%m-%d') <  '2019-08-01'
```

Then second query to know total sales on August:

```
select sum(uorpd_qty)
from user_order_product
left join user_order on user_order_product.uor_id = user_order.uor_id 
where uor_status = 'completed'
and uorpd_is_free = 0 
and date_format(uor_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2019-08-01'
and date_format(uor_date, '%Y-%m-%d') <  '2019-09-01'
```

Then third query to know last date purchased on August:

```
select datediff(now(),max(uor_date))
from user_order_product
left join user_order on user_order_product.uor_id = user_order.uor_id 
where uor_status = 'completed'
and uorpd_is_free = 0
and date_format(uor_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2019-08-01'
and date_format(uor_date, '%Y-%m-%d') <  '2019-09-01'
```

How can I subtract first query and second query then divide by third query ?

```
select sum(-uorpd_qty) + (select floor(sum(uorpd_qty * 20/100 + (uorpd_qty))) '20%'
                         from user_order_product
                          left join user_order on user_order_product.uor_id = user_order.uor_id 
                          where uor_status = 'completed'
                         and uorpd_is_free = 0
                         and date_format(uor_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2019-07-01'
                         and date_format(uor_date, '%Y-%m-%d') <  '2019-08-01')tar
from user_order_product
left join user_order on user_order_product.uor_id = user_order.uor_id 
where uor_status = 'completed'
and uorpd_is_free = 0 
/ (select datediff(now(),max(uor_date))
from user_order_product
left join user_order on user_order_product.uor_id = user_order.uor_id 
where uor_status = 'completed'
and uorpd_is_free = 0)divii
[[AND date_format(uor_date,'%Y-%m-%d') >= {{start_date}}]]
[[AND date_format(uor_date,'%Y-%m-%d') <= {{end_date}}]]

select floor(sum(uorpd_qty * 20/100 + (uorpd_qty))) '20%'
from user_order_productenter code here
left join user_order on user_order_product.uor_id = user_order.uor_id
where uor_status = 'completed'
and uorpd_is_free = 0
and date_format(uor_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2019-07-01'
and date_format(uor_date, '%Y-%m-%d') < '2019-08-01'
```

Comment: Provide table schema and sample data as insert statements. Provide a scenario and expected output.

Comment: Are you asking about doing a `SELECT ((SELECT ...) - (SELECT ...)) / (SELECT ...)`? You can do just math operations in a `SELECT` statement. For example: `SELECT (7 - 2) / 3` and each expression can be a sub-select.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing the calculation on only 1 table, I guess the expected result can be accomplished using CASE statements -

```
SELECT (FLOOR(SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(uor_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2019-07-01' 
                        AND DATE_FORMAT(uor_date, '%Y-%m-%d') <  '2019-08-01'
                            THEN uorpd_qty * 20/100 + uorpd_qty END)) - 
        SUM(CASE WHEN date_format(uor_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2019-08-01'
                  AND date_format(uor_date, '%Y-%m-%d') <  '2019-09-01'
                      THEN uorpd_qty)) / 
        CASE WHEN date_format(uor_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2019-08-01'
              AND date_format(uor_date, '%Y-%m-%d') <  '2019-09-01'
                  THEN DATEDIFF(NOW(),MAX(uor_date)) '20%'
FROM user_order_product UOP
LEFT JOIN user_order UO on UOP.uor_id = UO.uor_id
WHERE uor_status = 'completed'
AND uorpd_is_free = 0
```

Without test data it is hard to test this query, but it might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since the table sources and `WHERE` conditions are the same for last two, combine them in one aggregate query and `CROSS JOIN` to first. From there, run your arithmetic at outer level:

**Specific (July/August) Query**

```
SELECT (July_target.`20%` - Aug_sales.total_qty) / Aug_sales.days_since AS Final_Value
FROM
   (select floor(sum(uorpd_qty * 20/100 + (uorpd_qty))) AS `20%`
    from user_order_product
    left join user_order on user_order_product.uor_id = user_order.uor_id 
    where uor_status = 'completed'
    and uorpd_is_free = 0
    and date_format(uor_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2019-07-01'
    and date_format(uor_date, '%Y-%m-%d') <  '2019-08-01') AS July_target

CROSS JOIN
   (select sum(uorpd_qty) AS total_qty,
           datediff(now(), max(uor_date)) AS days_since
    from user_order_product
    left join user_order on user_order_product.uor_id = user_order.uor_id 
    where uor_status = 'completed'
    and uorpd_is_free = 0 
    and date_format(uor_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2019-08-01'
    and date_format(uor_date, '%Y-%m-%d') <  '2019-09-01') As Aug_sales
```

---

**General (All Months) Query**

You can potentially generalize for ALL months by incorporating `GROUP BY` in aggregations and `INNER JOIN` on date with one-month lag. Below normalizes dates to first of month:

```
SELECT target.month_date AS target_month,
       actual.month_date AS actual_month,
       (target.`20%` - actual.total_qty) / actual.days_since AS Final_Value
FROM
   (select CAST(DATE_FORMAT(mydate ,'%Y-%m-01') AS DATE) AS month_date,
           floor(sum(uorpd_qty * 20/100 + (uorpd_qty))) AS `20%`
    from user_order_product
    left join user_order on user_order_product.uor_id = user_order.uor_id 
    where uor_status = 'completed'
    and uorpd_is_free = 0
    group by CAST(DATE_FORMAT(mydate ,'%Y-%m-01') AS DATE)
   ) AS target

INNER JOIN
   (select CAST(DATE_FORMAT(mydate ,'%Y-%m-01') AS DATE) AS month_date,
           sum(uorpd_qty) AS total_qty,
           datediff(now(), max(uor_date)) AS days_since
    from user_order_product
    left join user_order on user_order_product.uor_id = user_order.uor_id 
    where uor_status = 'completed'
    and uorpd_is_free = 0 
    group by CAST(DATE_FORMAT(mydate ,'%Y-%m-01') AS DATE)
   ) AS actual

ON target.month_date = DATE_SUB(actual.month_date, interval 1 month)
```

---

**General (All Months) Query with CTE**

Alternatively, now supported in MySQL 8, run a self-join of a [common table expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) (CTE)

```
WITH cte AS
 (select CAST(DATE_FORMAT(mydate ,'%Y-%m-01') AS DATE) AS month_date,
         floor(sum(uorpd_qty * 20/100 + (uorpd_qty))) AS `20%`,
         sum(uorpd_qty) AS total_qty,
         datediff(now(), max(uor_date)) AS days_since
  from user_order_product
  left join user_order on user_order_product.uor_id = user_order.uor_id 
  where uor_status = 'completed'
  and uorpd_is_free = 0
  group by CAST(DATE_FORMAT(mydate ,'%Y-%m-01') AS DATE)
 )

SELECT target.month_date AS target_month,
       actual.month_date AS actual_month,
       (target.`20%` - actual.total_qty) / actual.days_since AS Final_Value
FROM AS cte AS target
INNER JOIN cte AS actual
ON target.month_date = DATE_SUB(actual.month_date, interval 1 month)
```